# Create a SQL-like Sequence in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have an SQL query having Sequence in it.

How can I Create a Sequence Like we create in SQL in Clickhouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clickhouse don't support sequences like a postgresql or other RDBMS
what is your use case?

you need insert data with incremented sequence ? what for? 
or you need sequenceMatch and sequenceCount functions for funnel analyze?

may be it's url will helfull
https://clickhouse.yandex/reference_en.html#sequenceMatch(pattern)(time,+cond1,+cond2,+...)

Comment: Yes, I want to insert data with incremented sequence.

Comment: And can you tell me how to make unique key and foreign key.

Comment: Clickhouse don't support foreign key and unique key features
this patterns not required for analytics screnario workload

try use raw UUID FixedString(16) for unique identifier
or prepare data batches in other DBMS before insert into clickhouse

Comment: I can add data on a DML query using Trigger. So, is there a way to create Trigger in clickhouse.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is what you are looking for?

```
-- Generate a sequence of dates from 2010-01-01 to 2010-12-31
select toDate('2010-01-01') + number as d FROM numbers(365);
```

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/table-functions/numbers/